# How to keep a 'tally' of other attributes as its own class attribute

Tags: java

I'm coding a `Hand` class for a card game, and I'd like to be able to keep track of how many cards of each `Suit` are in `Hand`. I'm storing an `ArrayList` of type `Card` in `Hand`, which acts as my Hand. So this is how I'm keeping track of the amount of each `Suit` within `Hand` currently:

```
public class Hand {
    private ArrayList<Card> hand;
    private int clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades;

    public Hand() {
        hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
        clubs = 0;
        diamonds = 0;
        hearts = 0;
        spades = 0;
    }

    public Hand(Hand otherHand) {
        this.hand.addAll(otherHand.hand);
        CountSuits(otherHand.hand);
    }

    public Hand(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
        clubs = 0;
        diamonds = 0;
        hearts = 0;
        spades = 0;
        this.hand = hand;
        CountSuits(hand);
    }

    public void CountSuits(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
        clubs += Collections.frequency(cards, Card.suit.CLUBS);
        diamonds += Collections.frequency(cards, Card.suit.DIAMONDS);
        hearts += Collections.frequency(cards, Card.suit.HEARTS);
        spades += Collections.frequency(cards, Card.suit.SPADES);
    }
}
```

Is this a messy/incorrect way of doing this? It's giving odd outputs when testing which makes me think it's not watertight, and there's probably a better way. Here's my `Card` class:

```
public class Card {
    public enum rank {ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING};
    private rank Rank;
    public enum suit {CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES};
    private suit Suit;

    public Card() {
        Rank = null;
        Suit = null;
    }

    public Card(rank Rank, suit Suit) {
        this.Rank = Rank;
        this.Suit = Suit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also add the Card class to the provided code?

Comment: I'm not sure that Collections.frequency would do what you want -- I'm assuming that `Card` is an object that has a property `suit`, which is an enum?

Comment: what do you mean 'odd outputs' is it right or not. ..... although i think i know what it is. change += to =. if you ever call count suits again it'll double everything.

Comment: Added Card @SamiFarhat and Gus

Comment: I think you are just counting the number of instances of that enum in your list, which is zero.

Comment: I don't think it's really worth it having dedicated variables for each suit, that will only have to be updated each time you draw or play a card. Assuming the number of cards in a hand is rather small, and this operation is not expected to be performed thousands of times a second, you could just calculate the numbers as needed with a helper method.

Comment: Have you considered using an `EnumMap` whose key is the suit and whose value is the number of appearances per suit type? This map will make your counting algorithm a lot simpler....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I would have used a `HashMap<Card.suit, ArrayList<Card>> hand;` and organised the cards by suit instead of using a whole encompassing array. This would involve iterating through the entire Hand in the constructor and placing each card in its rightful ArrayList.

Getting the size of a suit would then be achieved like below:

```
diamonds = hand.get(Card.suit.DIAMONS).size()
hearts = hand.get(Card.suit.HEARTS).size()
spades = hand.get(Card.suit.SPADES).size()
clubs = hand.get(Card.suit.CLUBS).size()
```

2) I haven't tested this but I don't think `Collections.frequency()` will work here. It will compare each entry in the provided collection (an object of type Card) with the type card.suit. You are essentially comparing objects of different types. The result from equals() which is used in frequency will be `false` for all.

3) Also, a few notes on the above code:

- Methods tends to start with lowerCase (e.g. CountSuits)
- Make methods you don't wish to expose `private`. (e.g CountSuits)
- It's good OOP practice to have constructors call each other using `super()`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store the cards as a map you can just use this to give you a map of the suits to their count.

```
Map<Card.suit, Long> map3 = things.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Card::getSuit, Collectors.counting()));
```